# Python 3 Count and While Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out an error in the code below. I need the following conditions to be met:

1) If equal to zero or lower, I need python to state "Invalid Input"

2) If greater than zero, ask whether there is another input

3) As long as there is another input, I need the program to keep asking

4) If "done", then I need Python to compute the lowest of inputs. I have not gotten to this part yet, as I am getting an error in the "done" portion.

```
print ("Lowest Score for the Racer.")
number = float(input("Please enter score: "))
if number < 0 or number == 0:
        print ("Input should be greater than zero.")
while True:
        number = float(input('Do you have another input? If "Yes" type another score, if "No" type "Done": '))
        if number < 0 or number == 0:
            print ("Input should be greater than zero. Please enter score: ")
        if number == "Done":
            print ("NEED TO COUNT")
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to modify your code according to your desired output. I think this should give you an idea. However there is still small things to deal in code. I suppose you can manage rest of it.

`empthy_list = []
print ("Lowest Score for the Racer.")
while True:
    number = float(input("Please enter score:  "))
    if number < 0 or number == 0:
        print ("Input should be greater than zero.")
    if number > 0:
        empthy_list.append(number)
        reply = input('Do you have another input? If "Yes" type another score, if "No" type "Done": ')
        if reply == "Yes" :
            number = float(input("Please enter score: "))
            empthy_list.append(number)
        if reply == "Done":
            print("NEED TO COUNT")
            print("Lowest input is: ",min(empthy_list))
            break`

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it now and will work on other errors.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an alternative solution which is more robust regarding input errors. It might include some ideas for improving your code but probably isn't the best solution, either.

```
print ("Lowest score for the racer.")
valid_input = False
num_arr = []
while not valid_input:
   foo = input('Please enter score: ')
   try:
      number = float(foo)
      if number > 0:
         num_arr.append(number)
         valid_input = True
      else:
         raise ValueError
      while foo != 'Done' and valid_input:
         try:
            number = float(foo)
            if number > 0:
               num_arr.append(number)
            else:
               raise ValueError
         except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input! Input should be number greater than zero or 
"Done".')
         finally:
            foo = input('Do you have another input? If yes type another score, 
if no type "Done": ')
   except ValueError:
      print('Invalid input! Input should be number greater than zero.')
print("Input done! Calculating lowest score...")
print("Lowest score is ", min(num_arr))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try your suggestion now. Also, in the code above, I am trying to incorporate another "if", if the response is numerical to the "Yes" or "Done" question, print "Error". I greatly appreciate your time, I could not sleep all night and morning thinking about logic, and how to incorporate all these variables.